# Multiple line jquery tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make custom jquery tooltip appear as multiple line that adjusts to fixed width? So it not go in one long line (if 'title' attribute is very long). Because Now if I write long 'title' attribute, tooltip is displayed on one long line and it does not matter what width is set to tooltip element.

My code to get better understanding of what I'm asking:

http://jsfiddle.net/8XttH/

jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").append("<div class='tip'></div>");
  $("p[title]").each(function() {
      $(this).hover(function(e) {
        $().mousemove(function(e) {
            var tipY = e.pageY + 16;
            var tipX = e.pageX + 16;
            $(".tip").css({'top': tipY, 'left': tipX});
         });
      $(".tip")
        .html($(this).attr('title'))
        .stop(true,true)
        .fadeIn("fast");
        $(this).removeAttr('title');
    }, function() {
      $(".tip")
        .stop(true,true)
        .fadeOut("fast");
         $(this).attr('title', $(".tip").html());
    });
  });   
});
```

Comment: Silly me. I thought I used fixed width... I put it now and it seems to be working. Sorry about that.

Comment: Okay, vote to close this question then.

Comment: I will, need to wait 10 minutes for choosing answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a `max-width` on the tool tip box?

```
max-width: 100px;
```

Also set the height to auto so it increases as needed

```
height: auto;
```

The text will then wrap to the next line.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8XttH/3/)

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was using this, but I didn't :).

Answer (score 1):

Use this `css`

```
div.tip{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width:100px;

  border: 2px solid #FF0000; 
  background-color: #FF9999;
  display: none;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8XttH/2/